# proof checking - power set and family set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Decide if it is true that $P(A) \subseteq P(B) \implies \bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B $

where $P(A), P(B)$ are power set and $A,B$ are family of sets

My proof:

Let $x \in P(A)$ then we have $x\subseteq A$ the more $x \subseteq \bigcup A$ but as we know that $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$ then since $x\in P(A)$ we have $x \in P(B)$ what implies that $x\subseteq B$ the more we have $x \subseteq \bigcup B$ hence if $x\in P(A)$ and $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$ then we have $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$ because we showed that for every $x \subseteq \bigcup A$ we have $x \subseteq \bigcup B$ so it means that $\bigcup A \subseteq \bigcup B$

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: $x \in P(A)$ does not imply $x \in A$, but $x \subset A$.

Comment: OK, I've already edited post, now is better ?

Comment: $x \subseteq A$, does not mean that $x \subseteq \bigcup A$. In general, the write-up could be much more structured. I cannot make heads or tails from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in \cup A \Rightarrow \exists Y(Y \in A \text{ and } x \in Y)$, but $\{Y\} \in P(A) \Rightarrow \{Y\} \in P(B) \Rightarrow Y \in B \Rightarrow x\in \cup B$, because $x \in Y$. This proves it.

Comment: I've got two questions 1) @Henno said that $x \in P(A)$ does not imply that $x \in A$  but ${Y} \in P(B) \implies Y \in B$ how it works ? 2) can you explain the last step, why $x \in \bigcup B$

Comment: Oh its $\{Y\} \in P(B)$, brackets matters, because $\{Y\}$ is a subset of $B$ and therefore $Y \in B$. And if you find an element of $B$ which contains $x$ then $x \in \cup B$ (this is the definition of union)

Comment: ok thanks a lot